# How to Overcome Spring and Jbehave Versioning Problem?

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, versioning, jbehave

In our project we are using Spring 3.0.0.RELEASE, and now we are trying to add JBehave to our project.
Here the problem is **JBehave** latest 3.4.5(Release) version uses **Spring 2.5.6** (spring-context, spring-test).
then we got problem in dependencies in maven.

is there any solution to continue our project with Spring version 3.0 and Jbehave Spring version 2.5.6 without any conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JBehave will probably also work with Spring 3.0. You could simply try to exclude the transitive dependency from JBehave. I didn't test this but it should look similar to this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    ...         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
     ....
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: @Benjamin Muschko: I am a beginner for Maven Dependency Management. :(  in the above i need not to give version details for Spring?  it is better you give more detailed structure of POM as given above.  Thank You.

Comment: @azad: The [exclusion tag](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Exclusions) only supports `groupId` and `artifactId` subtags. You don't need to give it a version.

Comment: @Benjamin Muschko: yes, you given good example. in my case i am **using JBehave for Scenario testing on Spring Injected Test Cases, in this case i need to have context of Spring and it's test Classes**. By exclusion of them our main goal will be missed out. If you know anything that will work in both cases (having Jbehave 2.5.6(spring) and our framework 3.00 Release by using maven dependency or anything). Please let me know. Thank You.

Comment: @azad: I didn't want to imply that do you not have to declare the Spring libraries as dependencies. You still do need to do that. You have to exclude them from JBehave though. Declare the JBehave dependency with the scope `test` and the Spring libraries with the scope `compile`. I changed the `pom.xml` to give you the idea.

Comment: @ Benjamin Muschko: as you told i changed pom.xml, but the problem is it's unable to find out the .story files in my class path.

Comment: @azad: Do you have them under `src/test/resources`?

Comment: @ Benjamain Muschko: Thank you for your information. at present we Removed Spring Dependency for Jbehave. and we are fallowed different approach.  our approach (doing dependency Management) looks tricky. any way thanks for your help. :)